# How to fix my zoom

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, zooming

I have a zoom where the image scaletype should be matrix so that the zoom work, but it's a perfect zooming for imageview inside a viewpager,where you can zoom and scroll through the image without any trouble, but I don't know how to fix the scaletype thing I need it to be fitxy, does anyone have a good zoom?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I had to replace :

```
DisplayType.NONE
```

with

```
DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN
```